# Python right-hand value binding

Tags: python, syntax

This might be an extremely noob python question however I'm curious.

Is it possible to make right-hand value binding (not sure about terminology) in python?

Here's some code:

```
>>> d = {'a':1 , 'b': 2 }
>>> d['a']
1
>>> temp = d['a']
>>> temp
1
>>> temp = 4
>>> temp
4
>>> d
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

Can we use `temp` as a *shortcut* of `d['a']`? So when we do `temp = 4`, the last line to print `{'a': 4, 'b': 2}`?

Does any syntax to do it exist or the only way to update the `d['a']` value is by `d['a'] = 4`?

Comment: Sadly, there are no pointers in Python.

Comment: However if `d['a']` was a mutable object (e.g. a `list`) you could alter it (e.g. `append` an object) via `temp`.

Comment: @AlexThornton All Python variables are in fact pointers.

Comment: @AlexThornton I'm talking about a mutable value; you're right that keys can't be mutable/hashable

Comment: @arshajii I suppose what I meant was that there isn't really easy pointer handling like for example in C.

Comment: what do you really want to do?

Comment: Perhaps not a duplicate, but certainly related: [Python: How do I pass a variable by reference?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/986006/395760)

Comment: @delnan: I was just about to post the same thing. Dupe hammer time anyway?

Comment: @delnan: [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15085529/why-doesnt-an-attribute-value-in-a-dictionary-within-a-class-refer-to-the-same) was closed as a dupe of that canonical post, I feel justified in closing this as a dupe of at least that one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such feature in Python. You could create an object that represents a reference to the according map entry and that has methods to set the the map's value, but that is not specifically supported by Python syntax.